# jQuery find/each script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

there must be something small ive overlooked here. I'm simply trying to select all DT elements in a DL and insert some HTML and add a click event, however it only seems to be applying to the first DT.

Here's the snippet from my plugin:

```
 return this.each(function(){ 
           var questions = $(this).find('dt');
            questions.each(function(){

                $(this).attr("title","Show answer"); // add screen tip
                $(this).wrapInner("<span class='faqToggleQues' />");
                $(this).prepend("<span class='faqToggleNumber'>"+numPrefix+(i+1)+numSubfix+"</span>");

            });
        });
```

Also I have hosted the code on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mindfriction/u6WYQ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the new link you have provided i have updated the code http://jsfiddle.net/u6WYQ/6/
 need to use defaults.numPrefix instead just numPrefix.Also you can hide dd default in by having init method.Also merge the options with default to apply user settings.

Comment: sorry kvc, i added the wrong jsfiddle link.. It should be ttp://jsfiddle.net/mindfriction/u6WYQ/

Comment: I found the issue an underclared variable was throwing out jQuery so it didnt proceed to the next loop of the each function..

Comment: yes i have passed the num prefix from defaults variable,you can check the modified code in the link i have posted

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('dt').each(function(){

                $(this).attr("title","Show answer"); // add screen tip
                $(this).wrapInner("");
                $(this).prepend(""+numPrefix+(i+1)+numSubfix+"");

            });

});
```

Comment: Hi Sudhir, this is within a plugin though hence why its in the  "return this.each(function(){  }" block.. The plugin is being called like so $('dl#faq').faqToggle()

Answer (score 0):

See my updated code http://jsfiddle.net/u6WYQ/11/

1. declare the default options `$.fn.faqToggle.defaults` before processing them in `$.extend`
2. for incrementing question number, refer to inner .each (the one with `idx`), not the outer .each (as referenced by `i`)
3. call the custom jquery method `faqToggle` in the `(function($){ ... }(jQuery))` body, not outside

The complete code

```
                (function($){
    $.fn.faqToggle = function(options){
        // declare the default options before processing them
        $.fn.faqToggle.defaults = {
          numPrefix: 'Q',
          numSubfix: '.',
          showTooltip:'Show answer',
          hideTooltip:'Hide Answer'
        }

        var opts = $.extend({},$.fn.faqToggle.defaults, options);


        function onClick(){
             if ( $(this).next('dd').is(":hidden") ) { // if the answer is hidden show it
                $(this).next('dd').show();
                $(this).attr("title","Hide answer"); // update screentip
            } else {
                $(this).attr("title","Show answer"); // update screentip
                $(this).next('dd').hide(); // if the answer is shown hide it
            }
        }


        return this.each(function(i){

            var questions = $(this).find('dt');
            var answers = $(this).find('dd');
            answers.hide(); // hide answers initially

            // for incrementing question number, referto inner .each, not the outer
            questions.each(function(idx){
                $(this).attr("title","Show answer"); // add screen tip
                $(this).wrapInner("<span class='faqToggleQues' />");
                $(this).prepend("<span class='faqToggleNumber'>"+opts.numPrefix + (idx+1) + opts.numSubfix+"</span>");

                $(this).click(onClick);

            });



        });


    };

// apply the custom jquery method in the (function($){ ... }(jQuery))
  $('#faqList').faqToggle();
})(jQuery);
```